# get values of multiple checkboxes in extbase/fluid TYPO3

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-flow

How to get values of multiple checkboxes checked in frontend template with fluid and use these values in action extbase?

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare the argument in your controller action and give it a type `array` or an array-compatible type which can be constructed by the PropertyMapper.
2. Name all fields the same as this argument.
3. Post the data and use the argument in the controller action.

This is the correct way of receiving an array as value of a controller argument. Accessing it directly from the request is *not recommended*, unless you also declared the argument on the controller action. Not doing so will bypass important argument processing.

Answer (score 0):

save them in a form and retrieve the POST data trough:

```
 $this->request->getArgument('variable')
```